# Ubuntu 22 04 on Google Chromebook Pixel 2013 Top Row keys Remapping

Tags: keyboard-layout

Had Google OS on Google Chromebook Pixel 2013 with OS end of life went to Gallium then Elementary OS which was Ok . Love Ubuntu 22 04 but top row of keys has been re mapped to other functions, not even sure what some do. Anyone know how to re map the top row keys to restore original as labeled function  ESC , Arrow<  Arrow> ,refresh,screen?, screen smaller, dim screen, brighten screen,kill volume, lower vol, raise volume and
POWER (which works  Ok)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Replace this file contents below, (don't forget backup first)
Backup command `mv /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc.old`

`/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc`

```
default  partial alphanumeric_keys modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "pc105" {

    key <ESC>  {    [ Escape        ]   };

    // The extra key on many European keyboards:
    key <LSGT> {    [ less, greater, bar, brokenbar ] };

    // The following keys are common to all layouts.
    key <BKSL> {    [ backslash,    bar ]   };
    key <SPCE> {    [    space      ]   };

    include "srvr_ctrl(fkey2vt)"
    include "pc(editing)"
    include "keypad(x11)"

    key <BKSP> {    [ BackSpace, BackSpace  ]   };

    key  <TAB> {    [ Tab,  ISO_Left_Tab    ]   };
    key <RTRN> {    [ Return        ]   };

    key <CAPS> {    [ Caps_Lock     ]   };
    key <NMLK> {    [ Num_Lock      ]   };

    key <LFSH> {    [ Shift_L       ]   };
    key <LCTL> {    [ Control_L     ]   };
    key <LWIN> {    [ Super_L       ]   };

    key <RTSH> {    [ Shift_R       ]   };
    key <RCTL> {    [ Control_R     ]   };
    key <RWIN> {    [ Super_R       ]   };
    key <MENU> {    [ Menu          ]   };

    // Beginning of modifier mappings.
    modifier_map Shift  { Shift_L, Shift_R };
    modifier_map Lock   { Caps_Lock };
    modifier_map Control{ Control_L, Control_R };
    modifier_map Mod2   { Num_Lock };
    modifier_map Mod4   { Super_L, Super_R };

    // Fake keys for virtual<->real modifiers mapping:
    key <LVL3> {    [ ISO_Level3_Shift  ]   };
    key <MDSW> {    [ Mode_switch       ]   };
    modifier_map Mod5   { <LVL3>, <MDSW> };

    key <ALT>  {    [ NoSymbol, Alt_L   ]   };
    include "altwin(meta_alt)"

    key <META> {    [ NoSymbol, Meta_L  ]   };
    modifier_map Mod1   { <META> };

    key <SUPR> {    [ NoSymbol, Super_L ]   };
    modifier_map Mod4   { <SUPR> };

    key <HYPR> {    [ NoSymbol, Hyper_L ]   };
    modifier_map Mod4   { <HYPR> };
    // End of modifier mappings.

    key <OUTP> { [ XF86Display ] };
key <KIDN> { [XF86KbdBrightnessDown] };
key <KIUP> { [XF86KbdBrightnessUp] }; 
key <KITG> { [XF86KbdLightOnOff] }; 

key <FK01> { [XF86Back] }; 
key <FK02> { [XF86Forward] };
key <FK03> { [XF86Reload] }; 
key <FK04> { [Print] }; 
key <FK05> { [Super_L] }; 
key <FK06> { [XF86MonBrightnessDown] }; 
key <FK07> { [XF86MonBrightnessUp] }; 
key <FK08> { [XF86AudioMute] }; 
key <FK09> { [XF86AudioLowerVolume] }; 
key <FK10> { [XF86AudioRaiseVolume] }; 

key <LWIN> { [Caps_Lock] };

};

hidden partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "editing" {
    key <PRSC> {
    type= "PC_ALT_LEVEL2",
    symbols[Group1]= [ Print, Sys_Req ]
    };
    key <SCLK> {    [  Scroll_Lock      ]   };
    key <PAUS> {
    type= "PC_CONTROL_LEVEL2",
    symbols[Group1]= [ Pause, Break ]
    };
    key  <INS> {    [  Insert       ]   };
    key <HOME> {    [  Home         ]   };
    key <PGUP> {    [  Prior        ]   };
    key <DELE> {    [  Delete       ]   };
    key  <END> {    [  End          ]   };
    key <PGDN> {    [  Next         ]   };

    key   <UP> {    [  Up           ]   };
    key <LEFT> {    [  Left         ]   };
    key <DOWN> {    [  Down         ]   };
    key <RGHT> {    [  Right        ]   };
};
```

Citation:
Bekir Aydoğan / Youtuber https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uRFBKXeBlR4

Comment: Might work but is this not DE dependent?

Comment: No. Almost all the linux comes with X11, it should work in Wayland, too.

Comment: Maybe you should say what DE you have used this in. May save some one a lot of grief.

Comment: All the Ubuntu flavor (Desktop Environment) uses X11 (a.k.a. X Window system). Ubuntu Gnome 22.04 LTS and later comes with Wayland. And Wayland should follow the XKB for keyboard layout. Hope you get it through my bad English.

Comment: Ubuntu Gnome 22.04 This does not exist Gnome is version 4

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 is a Gnome edition.

Comment: Thank you Sadaharu it is all good. Thats how champions do it.

Comment: The champions does everything, just like Bekir. I hardly understand how programs work and barely climb 1000 foot mountains. Mr. Brady, it was my honour at your service.

Comment: Worked wonderfully for me using Cinnamon on Ubuntu 22.04 on an Acer C738T Chromebook. Thank you!